# ActiveDocument.DowngradeDocument crashes Word with simple document

Tags: vba, ms-word, crash

Created a fairly simple document by copying some SharePoint content from the browser and pasted it into Word. I issue an `ActiveDocument.DowngradeDocument`  so I can programatically find building block content as I don't know how to access such from VBA. Usually the TOC is the only such nuisance.

Usually this command works as expected, but with this simple document it silently crashes Word which then restarts.

Re-installed Word 64-bit, no change. commented out line, everything worked, but I need to remove dynamic content.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the [Document.SaveAs2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/word.saveas2) method which saves the specified document with a new name or format. Some of the arguments for this method correspond to the options in the `Save As` dialog box (`File` tab). The `wdFormatDocument97` parameter stands for the Microsoft Word 97 document format.

Also you may try checking event logs in Windows when MS Word is crashed. Hardware and software events on the Windows operating system are stored in Windows event logs. The information stored in the Windows event logs will help you locate the possible threats and help you improve your system's functionality.